# Why does DestinationFiles and SourceFiles refer to different numbers of items?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, msbuild, devops

While attempting to build and publish an application via Azure DevOps using MSBuild, I'm getting the following error from MSBuild:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\
>   Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5327,5):
>
> Error MSB3094: "DestinationFiles" refers to 6 item(s), and
>   "SourceFiles" refers to 38 item(s). They must have the same number of
>   items.

It's not clear to me at all where this comes from, or what it means. I first thought this was related to an `<AfterTask>` section in the project file, which specified a set of files to copy over while publishing, but after realizing the whole section was unnecessary and removing it, the same error remains.

My application does seem to get built and published, but the build job in Azure DevOps reports it as having failed.

When looking for the path and file mentioned above, I realized that it does not exist locally on my machine; I'm running VS 2019, so I have a folder `2019` instead of the folder `2017` in the path above.

Furthermore, I have the Roslyn compiler, so under the `2019` folders I *do* have `msbuild\15.0\bin`, but instead of `amd64`, I have `Roslyn`.

The interesting thing here is that the settings in DevOps are specified *Latest* version of visual studio to build the project - presumably 2019 (that is an option in the drop down after all). So why does it refer to a path relying on VS 2017? And what exactly does the error mean, and how can I remove it?

---

**Update / additional info**

- The application is basically a Windows desktop application. It's a Click Once-application, with target framework .Net Framework 4.5.2.
- The pipeline is run by a custom agent. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the details regarding it.
- The Build Task is the default VS Build task directly avaialble in DevOps: 
  [image]
- Parameters to MSBuild are as follows (path changed, obviously):

`/t:publish /p:PublishDir='\\some\path\MyApplicationDir'`

- The platform is `x64`, and configuration is set to `release`

Comment: Can you share some details about your solution/project and your build task? Also, please run the pipeline with window2019 image if you're using hosted agent to run the pipeline.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Hi Lance. I've added some more details, is this enough to provide some more insight?

Comment: Can it build and publish well in local machine with msbuild.exe in command-line? Also, since you have VS2019 but it tries to run with VS2017, I think the agent running your pipeline is installed in another machine, try installing a new custom agent in your current machine and run the pipeline using that.